# Is there any way, we can access the client key-store using web app?

Tags: firefox, digital-signature, keystore, client-certificates

I want to apply digital signature on data submitted by client with his/her certificate installed in Firefox/Internet Explorer Browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User Authentication from Browser using Digital Signature Certificate on USB Token or Smart Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757258/user-authentication-from-browser-using-digital-signature-certificate-on-usb-toke)

Comment: You may use ActiveX in Internet Explorer if client configures IE to allow required permissions but using ActiveX or Java applets are older ways and not supported by modern browsers. Use any of the available modern browser extensions.

Comment: @BharatVasant if i use extension then every customer have to install an extra software(extension) which will hurt user experience. I want to make my web app capable of doing this using within firefox.

Comment: Did you have any clue / hint about how you plan to achieve this? I would be glad and curious to know the solution you develop for this...